# Alt + left-click not working anymore in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, edges, shortcut, selection-tools, loop

I don't know why but it seems <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> is not working for edge loop selection in blender 2.80. Is it a bug? Or is there's a new shortcut for that?

Comment: Did you make your Left Mouse Button your select button? It is Standard in 2.8 right? Did you have 2.79 installed before and it took the config from there?

Comment: Left button is the standard in 2.80. And i uninstalled 2.79 before using 2.8. I've got the solution,it's only double click(left click).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Linux Mint this will be an issue as <kbd>Alt</kbd> is used for moving and resizing windows.

Go to *System Settings > Windows* & then go to *Behavior* tab. Inside there you'll see *Special key* to move and resize windows and set it to <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> will work just as fine.

Answer (score 5):

As said by [morph3us](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/62926/morph3us), you can use <kbd>Double Click</kbd> on edge for the edge loop selection in edit mode, for Blender 2.8.

With default preferences (i.e. when you do *Load Factory Preferences*):

- You can select edge loop by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd> on desired edge.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Click</kbd>  for multiple edge loop selection.

With *modified preferences*(i.e. *Input > Emulate 3 Button Mouse* checked):

- You can select edge loop by <kbd>Double Click</kbd> on desired edge.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Double Click</kbd> for multiple edge loop selection.

Answer (score 3):

I am using *Blender 2.8 beta* on default settings and the shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>.

Comment: I'm using 2.79b and this work for me

Answer (score 3):

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Input* and turn off *Emulate 3 Button Mouse*.

Answer (score 2):

Its just "double click", without the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button pressed, now.

Seems it got reverted back to the original behavior, you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to select an edge loop.

Comment: Does not select edge loop for me

Comment: You are right, it changed again. I updated my answer! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

None of the above works for me in blender 2.90.1.

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the bottom of the window indicates that I should left click to loop select, but when I click, nothing happens.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Doubleclick</kbd> = nothing, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Doubleclick</kbd> = nothing, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> = nothing.

It turns out it's my operating system (Linux Mint) that uses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for window operations. I used the solution where I re-assign <kbd>Alt</kbd> to the <kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows) key in the operating system, and now Blender works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 2.82, so I don't know if would work for you, but it definitely works for me.

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Input* and under the *Mouse* dropdown, untick *Emulate 3 Button Mouse*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in v3.12 Windows 11, and none of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations work with or without 3 button mouse emulation.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Double-Click</kbd> does work, for both edge and face modes.

Comment: ALT+SHIFT+LMB should work in v3.1.2 with the default keymap.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 2.93, I think. I dug through the keymap in preferences and found that mouse button 4 will select loops on my system. I didn't have time to do more research but maybe this could be a good place to start for some of the more highly motivated among us. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think I figured it out. In the keymap dialog in preferences under Mesh - Loop Select - Loop Select, mine were set to MB4 and MB5. Click the arrow to the right to reset to default. I'm using Corsair peripherals and will check ICue to see if that had something to do with it.

Comment: If you have a fix, here, it's one of those odd cases? I think it's be fair to close this one as not needing an answer.. if that's not the case, go ahead and edit to explain why, and we can re-open for you.