# Cannot select a row of vertices

Tags: shortcut, selection-tools, linux

As the title states:
I cannot use alt + right click to select a row of vertices.

I tried many things, and at first the OS was using the alt key, so I changed the default key to the superkey (windows key).

However that didn't change anything in blender.

I even tried all the things listed [here  -> https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124971/altleft-click-not-working]

No success. I am using blender version 2.82, and I am running linux (debian 10) as my host operating system.

Comment: Did you tried in a simple scene? Is the "select edge loop" operator works by it's own?

Comment: Hello :). Since 2.80 it's actually *Alt + left click* by default

Comment: Thank you, @JachymMichal! That worked! :)